# TOP command on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server to find a resource intensive process?

Tags: linux, unix, suse

I have a box running SLES but I can't run TOP, apparently it's not installed on the box, is there a way for me to find a resource intensive process that's slowing the box down?

Any help will be much appreiciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like

```
ps -eo pcpu,pid | sort
```

But may be you just can't locate `top`? Did you try `/usr/bin/top`?

Comment: You probably mean `sort -r`

Comment: No, I'd like to see the most cpu-intensive process at the end of the output.

Comment: @AlexanderBakulin Thanks, that did solve the problem :-)

Comment: @MaYaN: Glad to hear it!